# Pandas fillna is super slow, needed for get_dummies?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a data frame which I loaded from a csv in which many values are integers, but many entries are also simply blank.  When I call `pd.get_dummies(frame)` like so:

```
binary_frame = pd.get_dummies(frame, )
```

the resulting frame is unchanged, in other words, `get_dummies` appears to fail.  Thus I am filling in the frame with `fillna` as follows:

```
frame = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding="utf8")
frame.fillna(value="n/a", inplace=True)
```

However, this takes a staggeringly long time, and on any non-trivial number of rows, (>= 10000), my processor becomes pegged and my machine is unresponsive until I kill the process.

My question is, what is the best and fastest way to `get_dummies` when there are empty entries in the frame?  Should I be calling `fillna` on the original frame or is there a better way?

UPDATE: The failure to encode can be replicated with this.  Place this in `test.csv`

```
a,b,c
1,,
,-1,
2,1,
1,1,1
```

Then run

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
binary_df = pd.get_dummies(df)
print(binary_df.head(5))
```

And see the frame is unchanged.  Now try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.fillna("n/a", inplace=True)
binary_df = pd.get_dummies(df)
print(binary_df.head(5))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the resulting frame is unchanged"? It is either created or not. Is it created? Do you get any error message?

Comment: @DyZ, I put this in "test.csv" `a,b,c \ 1,, \ ,-1, \ 2,1, \ 1,1,1` and then ran this: `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv") \ binary_df = pd.get_dummies(df)`  You can see `binary_df` is the same as `df`.

Comment: It is not clear from your code how the dummies are related to reading a CSV file. Please include an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: reproduction added to question...

Comment: Please add it to the question, not to a comment. We need to be able to copy and paste legally formatted Python code.

Comment: @DyZ  yep you got it, check the update, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `get_dummies` to work, all columns of a DataFrame must be categorical variables (e.g., strings). If a column is not categorical, it is ignored.

So, one way to handle your data is to convert the DataFrame to strings:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str))
#   a_1.0  a_2.0  a_nan  b_-1.0  b_1.0  b_nan  c_1.0  c_nan
#0      1      0      0       0      0      1      0      1
#1      0      0      1       1      0      0      0      1
#2      0      1      0       0      1      0      0      1
#3      1      0      0       0      1      0      1      0
```

Alternatively, consider turning off the `na_filter` option when reading the CSV file. You will not have NaNs in the first place:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", na_filter=False)
pd.get_dummies(df)
   a_  a_1  a_2  b_  b_-1  b_1  c_  c_1
0   0    1    0   1     0    0   1    0
1   1    0    0   0     1    0   1    0
2   0    0    1   0     0    1   1    0
3   0    1    0   0     0    1   0    1
```